# jQuery, active menu-item in menu-Navigation-bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery code that "colors the active menu item" in the my navigation menubar.

I found it online, and I find little of it hard to understand.

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.10.2.js" />
$(document).ready(function () {

    SetNavigation();
});

function SetNavigation() {

    var pathName = window.location.pathname;

    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
    path = decodeURIComponent(path);

    $("#topnavnmenu a").each(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        if (path.substring(0, href.lenght) == href) {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass("active");
        }
    })

}
```

Questions to the above displayed code:

1. Why is he doing that:

   ```
   path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
   ```
2. Should he not make sure before Comparison of Url and  
   that `<a href = " "` is taken before parameters

IF yes, how to write code for it ?

```
$("#topnavnmenu a").each(function () {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    if (path.substring(0, href.lenght) == href) {
       $(this).closest('li').addClass("active");
    }
})
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _`<a href = " "` is taken before parameters_

Answer (score 0):

> Why is he doing that: path = path.replace(//$/, "");

The regex `\/$` in :

```
path.replace(/\/$/, "");
```

Used just to remove (replace by empty) the last slash `/` in the path.

Example :

```js
console.log('www.website.com/'.replace(/\/$/, "")); //Remove last slash
console.log('www.website.com/page1/'.replace(/\/$/, "")); //Remove last slash
console.log('www.website.com/page2'.replace(/\/$/, "")); //No slash no change
```

Answer (score 0):

> 2. Should he not make sure before Comparison of Url and that

Not 100% sure what u mean by this, but the way "he" has coded this if even if href or comparison is 'undefined' the execution will not stop.
Function simply gives active class to all matching menu items.

For the function it dosent matter if all or none match. Since function executed in document ready its safe to assume all href attributes are already existing and therefore they will be found.